# Mysql Prepare statement take column value in variable

Tags: mysql, variables, prepared-statement

can anyone give me any idea about how to take column value into a variable.
FOR EXAMPLE -

Declare TD int;
Declare Cnew Varchar(10);

SET @a = Concat('Select Count(*) into ', TD,  'From tb1
Where C1 =', Cnew, ';');

how to take the count(*) into TD????

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want this:

```
Declare @TD int; 
Declare @Cnew Varchar(10);
set @CNew = 'Some string'; -- or maybe this is a param passed to the sp
set @TD = (Select count(*) from tb1 where c1 like @cnew);
```

Will give the actual count in TD, not the stmt. I don't think you need to hav a prepared stmt for this.

Comment: I am using prepare statement as the table i want to query is in different database so my statement look like
Declare TD int; Declare CNew Varchar(10);
SET @a = Concat('Select Count(#) into', TD 'From db1.tb1 where C1 = CNew, ';');

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
set @TD = 0 ;
SET @a = Concat('Select Count(*) into @td From tb1 Where C1 =', Cnew, ';');
```

It will do